# Plotting a function which behaves differently over different domains in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have a function f(x) which is defined as

```
f(x) = x^2; x>0 & x<=1
     = x^3; x>1 & x<2
     = 2*x; elsewhere
```

How do I plot this in Matlab in the same graph?

Comment: How would you plot *one* section of it?

Comment: I used fplot with limits and it works for any one of them. But I don't know how to plot all of them together.

Comment: after you plot each one use `hold on` command to keep the previous plot `on`.

Comment: @NKN tried it. Doesn't work. It only shows the last one.

Comment: the answer to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648914/matlab-plot-multiple-anonymous-functions-using-fplot

Comment: That question describes plotting two different function in the same limits. I want to plot different function in different limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this without `fplot` :

```
x = 0:0.1:3;
x1 = x(x>0 & x<=1);
x2 = x(x>1 & x<2);
x3 = x(x>2);
y1 = (x1).^2;
y2 = (x2).^3;
y3 = 2*(x3);
plot([x1 x2 x3], [y1 y2 y3])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define a set of `x` values (say between `4 <= x <= 4`), then apply `2*x` to every value within this interval.  After, search for those `x` values that are within the intervals of the other functions and set those values to what they should be within those intervals.  As such, try something like this:

```
x = -4 : 0.001 : 4;
y = 2*x;
y(x > 0 & x <= 1) = x(x > 0 & x <= 1).^2;
y(x > 1 & x < 2) = x(x > 1 & x < 2).^3;
plot(x,y);
grid;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: almost the same seconds!

Comment: @NKN - ahaha by 12 seconds!