# Plot a graph, combining solutions for multiple domains

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a question about plotting. I try to make a plot from two solutions where I took them solving two PDEs  on different spatial domains. In the first domain, I have solve a coupled system of PDEs with a discretization of the x =linspace(0,1,50).

In addition, in the second domain, I solved a PDE with spatial discretization of x = linspace(1,2).

How can I plot the solutions u1 and u2 into one graph?

The main point is that the overall solution has a discontinuity and a want a vertical line, like the step function.

I have seen the page [Plotting a function which behaves differently over different domains in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453777/plotting-a-function-which-behaves-differently-over-different-domains-in-matlab#26454364), there is another way, because I do not have the specific expression of each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just combine the vectors into one big vector and plot the combined vector as follows:

```
x1 = linspace(0,1,50);
x2 = linspace(0,2);
u1 = % solution of PDE for x1
u2 = % solution of PDE for x2
x = [x1 x2];
u = [u1 u2];
plot(x, u);
```